# Save a sequence of images using table with 2D variables

Tags: export, image, animation, gif-format

How can I save a sequence of images with 2D variables using `Table` into a gif file? I get an

> `Iterator {r,{-1,-1},{1,1},{0.1,0.1}} does not have appropriate bounds. >>`

error when I evaluate the following piece of code:

```
pgrid = 
  Graphics[Flatten[Table[Point[{i,j}], {i, -2, 2, 0.1}, {j, -2,2, 0.1}]], 
    Axes-> True, AxesOrigin -> {-2, -2}, PlotRange -> {{-2, 2}, {-2, 2}}] ;

dat1 =
  Table[
    Show[
     pgrid, 
     Graphics[{
       {Yellow, Opacity[0.5], Disk[{r[[1]] + q[[1]], r[[2]]+ q[[2]]}, 0.85]}, 
       Circle[{0, 0}, 0.85], 
       {Dashed, Circle[{0, 0}, 1.7]}, 
       {Blue, Thick, Arrow[{{0, 0}, {r[[1]], r[[2]]}}]},
       {Red, Thick, Arrow[{{0, 0}, {q[[1]], q[[2]]}}]}, 
       {Blue,Thick, Arrow[{{q[[1]], q[[2]]}, {r[[1]] + q[[1]], r[[2]] + q[[2]]}}], 
        Green, Arrow[{{0, 0}, {r[[1]] + q[[1]], r[[2]] + q[[2]]}}]},
       {Purple, Thick, Circle[{q[[1]], q[[2]]}, 0.85]}}]],
  {r, {-1, -1}, {1, 1}, {0.1, 0.1}}, {q, {-2, -2}, {2, 2}, {0.1, 0.1}}];

SetDirectory @ NotebookDirectory[]
Export["gif.gif", dat1]
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are several issues here. First, it is not clear for your *2D variables* whether you want

```
Table[{r, r}, {r, -1, 1, .5}]

(* {{-1., -1.}, {-0.5, -0.5}, {0., 0.}, {0.5, 0.5}, {1., 1.}} *)
```

or, you want something like

```
Table[{rx, ry}, {rx, -1, 1, .5}, {ry, -1, 1, .5}]

(* {{{-1., -1.}, {-1., -0.5}, {-1., 0.}, {-1., 0.5}, {-1., 
   1.}}, ... {{0.5, -1.}, {0.5, -0.5}, {0.5, 0.}, {0.5, 0.5}, {0.5, 
   1.}}, {{1., -1.}, {1., -0.5}, {1., 0.}, {1., 0.5}, {1., 1.}}} *)
```

If you want the first version, then you can simply replace your table with

```
dat1 = Table[code, {r, -1, 1, .1}, {q, -2, 2, 0.1}]
```

and replace every `r[[.]]` or `q[[.]]` with `r` and `q`. If you want the second case, then you can split your `r` (and `q`) iterator in `rx` and `ry` as I did. Beware that you get a deeply nested list from this which needs to be [`Flatten`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Flatten.html)'ed appropriately.

The other issue is, that you try to export a matrix of graphics as `"GIF"` image. While a list of images will end in an gif animation, a matrix of images seems not to make sense, but I haven't checked the documentation carefully.

### Edit:

> Tell me why this doesnt work : Table[{A[[1]], A[[2]]}, {A, {-1, -1}, {1, 1}, {0.1, 0.1}}]

Because *Mathematica* is a programming language, which needs you to enter correct syntax. It cannot guess what you want it to do. If you read the documentation to [`Table`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Table.html) you will see that your kind of input style is not supported.

### Edit 2:

> what if I want the second one?

You just create your own table-command which does what you want:

```
SetAttributes[myTable, {HoldAll}];
myTable[body_, {var_Symbol, {min1_, min2_}, {max1_, max2_}, {step1_, step2_}}] :=
  Flatten[Table[With[{var = {i1, i2}}, body], 
  {i1, min1, max1, step1}, {i2, min2, max2, step2}], 1];
myTable[body_, iter1_List, restIter__List] := 
 Flatten[myTable[myTable[body, iter1], restIter], 1]
```

and then you can try

```
myTable[{A[[1]], A[[2]]}, {A, {-1, -1}, {1, 1}, {0.5, 0.5}}]

(* {{-1., -1.}, {-1., -0.5}, {-1., 0.}, {-1., 0.5}, {-1., 
  1.}, {-0.5, -1.}, {-0.5, -0.5}, {-0.5, 0.}, {-0.5, 0.5}, {-0.5, 
  1.}, {0., -1.}, {0., -0.5}, {0., 0.}, {0., 0.5}, {0., 
  1.}, {0.5, -1.}, {0.5, -0.5}, {0.5, 0.}, {0.5, 0.5}, {0.5, 
  1.}, {1., -1.}, {1., -0.5}, {1., 0.}, {1., 0.5}, {1., 1.}} *)
```

or even

```
myTable[{A[[1]], A[[2]], B[[1]], B[[2]]}, 
  {A, {-1, -1}, {1, 1}, {0.5, 0.5}}, {B, {3, 4}, {5, 6}, {1, 1}}] // Shallow

(* {{-1., -1., 3, 4}, {-1., -0.5, 3, 4}, {-1., 0., 3, 
  4}, {-1., 0.5, 3, 4}, {-1., 1., 3, 4}, {-0.5, -1., 3, 
  4}, {-0.5, -0.5, 3, 4}, {-0.5, 0., 3, 4}, {-0.5, 0.5, 3, 4}, {-0.5, 
  1., 3, 4}, <<215>>} *)
```

Comment: Tell me why this doesnt work : Table[{A[[1]], A[[2]]}, {A, {-1, -1}, {1, 1}, {0.1, 0.1}}]

Comment: I dont want a matrix of graphics. Thats why I use show to overlap all the graphics into one image, and what if I want the second one ? - I have failed at flattening the array of coordinates properly. I just end up in error everytime ... (* {{{-1., -1.}, {-1., -0.5}, {-1., 0.}, {-1., 0.5}, {-1., 
   1.}}, ... {{0.5, -1.}, {0.5, -0.5}, {0.5, 0.}, {0.5, 0.5}, {0.5, 
   1.}}, {{1., -1.}, {1., -0.5}, {1., 0.}, {1., 0.5}, {1., 1.}}} *)

Answer (score 3):

I believe that you can achieve your desired result by generating by using iterators as in the following modification of your code:

```
pgrid = Graphics[
   Flatten[Table[Point[{i, j}], {i, -2, 2, 0.1}, {j, -2, 2, 0.1}]], 
   Axes -> True, AxesOrigin -> {-2, -2}, 
   PlotRange -> {{-2, 2}, {-2, 2}}];

dat1 = Flatten@
   Table[Show[pgrid, 
     Graphics[{{Yellow, Opacity[0.5], 
        Disk[{r[[1]] + q[[1]], r[[2]] + q[[2]]}, 0.85]}, 
       Circle[{0, 0}, 0.85], {Dashed, Circle[{0, 0}, 1.7]}, {Blue, 
        Thick, Arrow[{{0, 0}, {r[[1]], r[[2]]}}]}, {Red, Thick, 
        Arrow[{{0, 0}, {q[[1]], q[[2]]}}]}, {Blue, Thick, 
        Arrow[{{q[[1]], q[[2]]}, {r[[1]] + q[[1]], r[[2]] + q[[2]]}}],
         Green, Arrow[{{0, 0}, {r[[1]] + q[[1]], 
           r[[2]] + q[[2]]}}]}, {Purple, Thick, 
        Circle[{q[[1]], q[[2]]}, 0.85]}}]], {r, 
     Table[{j, j}, {j, -1, 1, 0.1}]}, {q, 
     Table[{j, j}, {j, -2, 2, 0.1}]}];
```

The processing time and file size for animate gif is large but I append animated gif with step size 0.4:

[image]

Comment: Yes! this is what I want to do. But this moves only diagonally , if I want it to move for every value of R and Q across the whole picture. What do I have to change ?

Comment: As you can see, the iteration for this diagonal movement is chosen from a set, i.e. {j,set} rather than {j,xmin,xmax,step}. I suggest you construct the set with particular attention to order of the elements as this is two dimensional and then enter into to Table commend. The difficulty (as I see it) is what you wanted Mathematica to do with {-1,1{,{1,1},{0.1,0.1}.

Comment: Yes that's the difficulty. I am still not able to figure out how to pass values  {-1,1{,{1,1},{0.1,0.1} which is a 2D variation.

Comment: See my edit 2, I have explained everything there.